# How to call the fields of a table A from table B when table B is containing the primary key of A as a foreign key (Springboot+JPA repo+MySQL+postman)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, postman, mysql-5.1

Can anyone let me know how to implement the joining of two tables using a foreign key?

The scenario here is as follows:

3 tables:

i. product_tbl : Having primary key with other fields.

ii. customer_tbl : Having primary key with other fields.

iii. purchase_tbl : Having a primary key, foreign key of above two tables, and some other fields.

I want to call other fields of 'product_tbl' with the foreign key present in 'purchase_tbl' and the same I want to do with 'customer_tbl' and 'purchase_tbl'.

I am using spring boot + JPA repository + MySQL 5.1.45+ postman.

The project structure is:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkdIo.png)

My try was to implement the below code marked with orange color:
I tried connect model class with one to one and other mapping style and wrote the '@Query(.....)' but I must be missing somewhere, I think.
['@Query(...)'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCeXi.jpg)

This query is being called by the controller class (see the commented segment):
[Controller Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx0L4.png)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please replace the screenshots with actual code snippets so that your question does not attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you already have relationship mapped in entity class. i.e. You purchaseModel entity should have a element

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "<<join field>>")
ProductModel productModel;
```

If yes, your relationship is already formed. All you need to do is to call the inner object using the outer object. In you case below will be the query

```
@Query("Select pt from PurchaseModel pt where pt.productModel.shoeCategory=?1)
List<PurchaseModel> findByCategory(String pc);
```

Comment: I tried joining objects, but not sure if that was correct or not. I will try you suggestion.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still getting [errors](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bPT9G68pafpapsC--tE1i-WpNPiujeVe/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share your classes your entity and repository class

Comment: [Here it is](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jiaAzYpfCOeQ52QYnNvyh60AO1GQpw0i?usp=sharing)